# CKEditor remove inline img style

Tags: ckeditor

I am using a responsive image technique setting a max-width of 100% with CSS.

This isn't working for any images added through CKEditor, as an inline style is added.

In CSS I have added a style to override the width, which works, but height: auto doesn't, so the images is stretched.

I need to find a way to stop CKEditor from adding the inline style in the first place.

I am using CKEditor 4.x

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since version 4.1, CKEditor offers so called [Content Transformations](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter-section-4) and already defines some of them. If you restrict in your [`config.allowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) that you don't want to have `width` and `height` in `<img>` styles, then editor will automatically convert styles to attributes. For example:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    allowedContent: 
        'img[!src,alt,width,height]{float};' + // Note no {width,height}
        'h1 h2 div'
} );
```

then:

```
<p><img alt="Saturn V carrying Apollo 11" class="left" src="assets/sample.jpg" style="height:250px; width:200px" /></p>
```

becomes in the output:

```
<p><img alt="Saturn V carrying Apollo 11" height="250" src="assets/sample.jpg" width="200" /></p>
```

and, as I guess, it completely solves your problem.

Comment: As far as I can see, it should also strip your `p` tags since they are are not permitted by your rules. I want to do this conversion without needing a monster white list of every possible tag and attr, i.e. with `allowedContent:true`, maybe like this:

`CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {ev.editor.filter.addTransformations([['img: sizeToAttribute']]);});`
to have it always convert styles to attributes, but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: FYI `p` is added by the editor as a must-have tag, provided `config.enterMode` is `ENTER_P`.

Comment: @Synchro is correct, using `allowedContent` requires you to white-list every tag, and attribute. I have posted an alternative, more suitable solution.

Answer (score 17):

A far better alternative to the accepted answer is to use `disallowedContent` ([see docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content)), as opposed to `allowedContent`.

Using `allowedContent` requires you to create a rather large white-list for every possible tag or attribute; where as `disallowedContent` does not; allowing you to target the styles to ignore.

This can be done like so:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    disallowedContent: 'img{width,height};'
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it completely removes the ability to set image dimensions in the popup...which is what you want for responsive. Cool.

Comment: It's not working in ckeditor 4.6 , here is the config.js http://pastebin.com/Dre5DskU

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  This will remove inline styling from all images without descrimination.  The question was "a way to stop CKEditor from adding the inline style in the first place."  Note *first place*, there are plenty of scenarios where inline css may be required.  The behavour of the image plugin automatically adding inline width and height of an image is the behaviour that the OP wants removed.

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to `instanceReady` event and alter any element before saving, in your case the `img` tag

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    ev.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
    {
        elements:
        {
            $: function (element) {
                // check for the tag name
                if (element.name == 'img') {
                    var style = element.attributes.style;

                   // remove style tag if it exists
                    if (style) {
                        delete element.attributes.style;
                    }
                }

                // return element without style attribute
                return element;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this solution works well. when I don't want to use allowContent