# CKEditor4.0, how to remove style attribute of <img> after uploading?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I uploaded an image to my server. Now I want to remove `style` attribute of `<img>` because I don't want inline styles like `height` and `width`, just initial size.

So, is there any method to execute in

```
window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction( funcNum, fileUrl [, data] )
```

Comment: is it what you are looking for link :-
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016605/ckeditor-remove-inline-img-style

Comment: @Saineshwar all right problem has been solved,thx

Comment: Kelvin can you vote up to my comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CKEditor remove inline img style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016605/ckeditor-remove-inline-img-style)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content 
this is what I need,thanks to @Saineshwar